# Undefined variable: no_marks (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am getting following error Undefined variable: no_student (Laravel 5.3)
Here is my view. blade

```
@foreach($no_marks as $no_mark)
                        <tr class="gradeX odd" role="row" id="">
                        <td style="display:none"></td>
     <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes checkbox-index" value="">
                     <span></span>
                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
@endforeach
```

**my index method in controller**

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $no_marks = Markno::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('no-mark.index');
}
```

**I am storing record using this store method**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
       'ip_range'     => 'required|max:255',
     ]);


    $ip_data['ip_range']           = $request->input('ip_range');
    $ip_data['min_ip']             = $request->input('ip_range');
    $ip_data['max_ip']             = $request->input('ip_range');
    $ip_data['list_id']            = $request->input('list_id');
    $ip_data['user_id']            = Auth::user()->id;


        $no_marks = Markno::create($ip_data);
        session()->flash('msg', ' Successfully created');
        return view('no-mark.index');
}
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help to fix it.

Comment: Change your index method to `return view('no-mark.index', compact('no_marks'));` to pass the data to the view.

Comment: thanks a lot its done

Answer (score 0):

You did not passed your variable `$no_marks` into your view that's why it is undefined to passed it

```
return view('no-mark.index', array('no_marks' => $no_marks));
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable available on controller you have to pass it on view like:

```
return view('no-mark.index', array('no_marks' => $no_marks));
```

here the second parameter is the array, you can access its index on view page

Answer (score 0):

please update your action

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $no_marks = Markno::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('no-mark.index',compact(['no_marks']));
}
```